# GLSL optimization for packed layout type

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to simulate something like polymorphism in GLSL with nested structs.

```
struct Primitve{
   Sphere s;
   Plane p;
   Triangle t;
   int type;
};
```

The integer type specifies what this primitive really is. In this way I can put all the primitives in one array. One disadvantage is the waste of memory.

So my question is about the "packed" layout type.
When I create a shader storage buffer with this type

```
layout(packed) buffer PrimitiveBuffer{
   Primitive primitives[];
};
```

will this block of data be optimized by not allocating data for members which aren't used at all? The Wiki says regarding to the packed layout: "Also, members of a block can be optimized out if they are found by the implementation to not affect the result of the shader."

Do I get this right or does it only regard to paddling due to alignment restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can* the compiler optimize elements away? Yes. *Will it*? Only if it can *statically* determine that they are unused.

Consider this function:

```
void ProcessPrimitive(int index)
{
  if(primitives[index].type == 0)
  {
    primitives[index].s ...
  }
  else if(primitives[index].type == 1)
  {
    primitives[index].p ...
  }
  else
  {
    primitives[index].t ...
  }
}
```

How can the compiler know that, for a *specific* index, what the `type` field will be? How can it know that a specific index will be a Sphere or whatever? It can't. Therefore, it cannot optimize anything away.

If you want to save space, you're going to have to implement data conversion yourself. So you will have to store generic "floats" of information in your Primitive, which can be converted into a Sphere/etc based on the type field.

Comment: Ok, that's what I have expected. Of course it can't be optimized when I do operations on the element in the code but when I don't touch the triangle member for example then the compiler would leave out the triangle, right? Doesn't it introduce another alignement in this case. Thus I would need to adapt the code which transfers data to this buffer?

Comment: @Stan: "*Thus I would need to adapt the code which transfers data to this buffer?*" You *always* had to "adapt the code" to the data. You gave up the rights to knowing what members would be there when you use `packed` instead of `std140` or `std430`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want to share your buffer across multiple shader programs, or not.

If you don't, you can use a **packed** memory layout, essentially telling your implementation: "Any variable in this block, that is not used (as in does not affect the outcome of the shader stage) may be optimized away."

Keep in mind though, that in this case, you have to explicitly [query](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object#Layout_queries) the location of members within the block.

In the end though, it's up to your GLSL implementation to find out what "does not affect the outcome of the shader". I suppose you'll have to do a bit of profiling.